# The dual of the Lefschetz operator under a perturbation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, hodge-theory

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a compact Kähler, or more generally, Hermitian manifold. Let $L_{\omega} : \Omega^k(X) \to \Omega^{k+2}(X)$ denote the *Lefschetz operator* given by $$L_{\omega}(\alpha) : = \omega \wedge \alpha.$$

The formal adjoint of $L_{\omega}$ is denoted by $\Lambda_{\omega} : \Omega^k(X) \to \Omega^{k-2}(X)$.

Suppose $\widetilde{\omega} : = C \omega + dd^c \varphi$ is Hermitian metric given scaling the positive $(1,1)$-form $\omega$ by a constant $C>0$ and perturbing $C \omega$ within its $dd^c$-cohomology class, where $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$.

> The Lefschetz operators are related by $$L_{\widetilde{\omega}}(\alpha) = C L_{\omega}(\alpha) + dd^c \varphi \wedge \alpha.$$

I would like to know if there are any results in the following direction:

> Is there a formula for the relation between $\Lambda_{\widetilde{\omega}}$ and $\Lambda_{\omega}$?

**Remark:** Of course, we may write $\Lambda = (-1)^k \star L \star$, where $\star$ denotes the Hodge-$\star$ operator, but this then reduces the problem to understanding the relationship between the Hodge-$\star$ operator of $\widetilde{\omega}$ and its relation to the Hodge-$\star$ operator of $\omega$.